# Upper bound of sum of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

The sum is $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n}$, where $0<a<1$. One easy upper bound is $\frac{a}{1-a}$. Are there any tighter upper bound available?

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n} = -\ln(1-a)$

Comment: Let $\displaystyle f(a) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n}$. Differentiate both sides. Apply geometric series. Integrate both sides.

Comment: Clearly the partial sums $\sum^N_{n=1} \frac{a^n}n$ are increasing (as $N$ increases) since we are simply adding more positive terms (when $0<a<1$). Thus they converge monotonically to their limit: $-\ln(1-a)$.

Comment: @DHMO Thank you very much!

Comment: @DHMO Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f(a) &=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n} \\
f'(a) &=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{na^{n-1}}{n} \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{n-1} \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n \\
&=& \dfrac1{1-a} \\
\displaystyle \int_0^a f'(a) \ \mathrm da &=& \displaystyle \int_0^a \dfrac1{1-a} \ \mathrm da \\
f(a) - f(0) &=& -\ln(1-a) - 0 \\
f(a) - 0 &=& -\ln(1-a) - 0 \\
f(a) &=& -\ln(1-a)\\
\end{array}$$